# Where to get insurance for capoeira students in UK?

Tags: finances, injuries, coaching, martial-arts

I recently moved to UK and figured that where I live (Crawley, West Sussex) there is no Capoeira school.

So I decided to organize a new club for training Capoeira. I found a nice location, one of the facilities from the council, but I need to sort out the insurance for the students and myself, so that in case anything happens we are covered.

I'm not sure how this type of insurance works.

- How should I approach this problem
- Who should I contact
- What kind of insurance I should get